# JQuery fomdata sending empty data to php file?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to upload file through jquery formdata without any form. My problem is that it is not sending any data to php file.

**Here is my jquery code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#e_picture').change(function() {

        var file_data = jQuery('#e_picture').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('e_picture', file_data);
        form_data.append('e_uid', '3585');

        //});
        // data: {e_uid: e_uid, e_picture:'23'},

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php?option=com_objectified&task=course_reg.addPicture",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                form_data
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(result) {
                alert('This is ' + result); // Here I show onlu e_uid but it alerts blank result
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name='e_picture' id='e_picture'>
```

Comment: Is your form multipart/formdata? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: Follow this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: @MarvinFischer I want to send data without form

Comment: Do you used $_FILES to get post data on index.php?

Comment: `contentType: false` <- why do you have this?

Comment: @Midhun1993 yes but I was just echoing `e_uid` for testing but it is alerting empty result under `success` method

Comment: @Phil I think its necessary for `formData`

Comment: Please check like this `echo $_POST['e_uid']` and `print_r($_FILES['e_picture'])`

Comment: @Midhun1993 blank results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the form_data in wrong way

instead of

```
data: {
   form_data
},
```

just send it like

```
data: form_data,
```

Comment: Oh Yesss.. Cool! Its working now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#e_picture').change(function() {

    var file_data = jQuery('#e_picture')[0].files;
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("e_picture[]", file_data[0]);
    form_data.append('e_uid', '3585');

    //});
    // data: {e_uid: e_uid, e_picture:'23'},

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_objectified&task=course_reg.addPicture",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            form_data
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(result) {
            alert('This is ' + result); // Here I show onlu e_uid but it alerts blank result
        }
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

ange content type to : 
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',